# Delete Work Item attachments using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

Pull request attachments can be deleted using REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-attachments/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

But I am not seeing similar option for the work item attachments:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Is there a workaround or some undocumented way to do it using HTTP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to perform `PATCH` request on work item for removing attachment using Azure DevOps REST API.

I have a work item with **attachment** as below in my Azure DevOps project:

[image]

To delete the work item attachment, I ran **`PATCH`** request with below request body:

```json
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?&api-version=7.0

[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/relations/0"
  }
]
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in DevOps portal where work item attachment **deleted** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Work Items - Update - REST API  | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#remove-an-attachment)

Comment: `op` specifies what operation to perform. `path` refers to path for that operation. `value` means value of operation. Initially, test operation will be performed in /rev path where value will be **revision number** of the work item.

Comment: You can run this query `GET https://dev.azure.com/orgname/projname/_apis/wit/workitems/6?$expand=all&api-version=7.0` to find **rev** value of work item like [this](https://i.imgur.com/WRxAQek.png).

Comment: To remove attachment, you need to give operation name as **remove** where `path` specifies which attachment to remove. These work item attachments are referred as **relations** that starts with index 0. So, `path` is '/relations/0' means first attachment of work item.